# How to update naviation property with new values in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Soo... I have this simple model for `Product`:

```cs
public class Product {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other things

    public ICollection<ProductAttribute> ProductAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

And `ProductAttributes` with `ProductId` and `Name` as multifield keys.

```cs
public class ProductAttribute {
    public int? ProductId { get; set; } // Key
    public ProductAttributeName? Name { get; set; } // Key
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And in my WebAPI project I have this method:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Patch(Product product) {
    var productExist = await _context.Products.AnyAsync(a => a.Id == product.Id);
    if (!productExist) return NotFound(product.Id);
    _context.Products.Update(product);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok();
}
```

And I assume that if someone sends my JSON with different data in `productAttributes` I should switch values to the new ones completely overriding
or deleting old values. Like in this example

```
OldProduct
* Name
* ProductAttributes:
    * Value 1
    * Value 2
```

```
NewProduct
* Name
* ProductAttributes:
    * Value 2
    * Value 3
```

So `Value1` should be deleted and `Value3` should be added. But instead, I'm getting an exception on `SaveChangesAsync()`:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added. Key: System.Object[]'
```

I guess it's probably because it's trying to add `Value2`, but it already exists.

How should I properly update the naviagation property?

@Update

Thanks to @cjens19 I just change update method and used Automapper:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Patch(Product product) {
    var productFromDb = await _context.Products.Include(p => p.ProductAttributes).SingleOrDefaultAsync(product1 => product1.Id == product.Id);
    if (productFromDb == null) return NotFound(product.Id);
    Mapper.Map(product, productFromDb);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you doing in the // ... Checking if model exist code?

You should be retrieving the existing Product entity out of the context with something like:

```
var entity = _context.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == product.Id);
```

Then, if entity is not null, you can set his properties with the values passed in with the Product param.

Lastly, you will call Update and Save. This shouldn't give you any ef core errors.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the edits. So you still aren't retrieving the entity out of the context. Rather than do an AnyAsync that returns a bool, you can do a SingleOrDefault (like in my original comment). You can still do a null-check on that since the OrDefault will return a null of the entity is not found. Then you can update the entity that is returned from that retrieval.

Comment: So... Instead of using `_context.Products.Update(product)` I should somehow map or manually assign new values to tracking entity retrieved from `SingleOr`?

Comment: Yes. Tracking will handle the updating for you after you map new values and do a SaveChanges.