# Why EF Core is changing state to Added after self mapping?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using EF Core (2.2.6) and AutoMapper (9.0.0) for entity mapping and I occurred a problem.

My profile:

```cs
CreateMap<Product, Product>();
```

This is my updating code:

```cs
public async Task<RepositoryResult> UpdateAsync(Product product) {
    var productFromDb = await _context.Products
        .Include(p => p.PreparationMethods)
        .Include(p => p.ProductAttributes)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == product.Id);

    if (productFromDb == null) return RepositoryResult.NotFound(product.Id.ToString());
    // product has state Detached here
    _mapper.Map(product, productFromDb); // <== HERE
    // product now has state Added
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RepositoryResult.Success();
}
```

After self-mapping (`await _context.SaveChangesAsync()`) I always get an `Exception`

```cs
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Product' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 18}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'
```

After some debugging, I found out that:

- `product` - has state `Added`
- `productFromDb` - has state `Modified`

And that's where my problem came from.

Why is AutoMapper (or EF Core) thinking that `product` should be added? How can I fix that?

@Update SOLVED

Okay. I've managed to solve this problem somehow (?). In my Controller, I had `GetById` method, which had `AsNoTracking()`, because it supposes to return `ReadOnly` values to avoid some changes by accident.

Damn... That's a really bad solution because I wanted it to return an object without tracking, but I guess it's impossible.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateQuantity(int id, ProductQuantity quantity) {
    var getResult = await _productRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);
    if (getResult.Code == RepositoryStatusCodes.NotFound) return NotFound(getResult.Errors);
    else if (!getResult.IsSuccess) return BadRequest(getResult.Errors);

    var product = getResult.EntityResult;
    product.Quantity = quantity.Quantity;

    var updateResult = await _productRepository.UpdateAsync(product);
    if (!updateResult.IsSuccess)
        return BadRequest(updateResult.Errors);
    else
        return Ok();
}
```

My get method:

```cs
public async Task<RepositoryResult<Product>> GetByIdAsync(int id) {
    var product = await _context.Products
        .Include(p => p.ProductAttributes)
        .Include(p => p.PreparationMethods)
        //.AsNoTracking() <--- comement on this sovled my problem
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);

    if (product == null)
        return RepositoryResult<Product>.NotFound(id.ToString());
    return RepositoryResult<Product>.Success(product);
}
```

Comment: Where is the product model coming from in ```public async Task<RepositoryResult> UpdateAsync(Product product)```? I mean how are you retrieving this model?

Comment: It's from Controller. Before mapping, he has state `Detached`

Comment: are `product` and`productFromDb` the same Type? if so, why not just attach it? (besides using for dto -> persistence model binding is screaming for getting hurt, not what Automapper was meant for)

Comment: Yes, they are. Somebody recommended me this approach because I also wanted to update navigation properties. By attaching do you mean `_context.Attach()`?

Comment: Entity Framework will update all properties in your Product model you're passing in. There's no need to map via AuotMapper. Just set the EntityState to modified and save changes.

Comment: I've tried, but it wasn't updating my navigation properties properly.

Comment: Why is `product` attached in the first place ? can you add more code where you created/obtained the parameter `product` ?

Comment: I think it's better to use a view model (ProductViewModel) with the specific properties you're collecting through the view instead of using an entity model of type Product.

Comment: @Fourat. I've checked and before mapping `product` has state `Detached`

Comment: If Jimmy Bogard would see this, Im pretty sure he wouldnt be happy. `CreateMap<Product, Product>` makes no sense IMO from the _mapping_ point of view, there is no _projection_ involved whatsoever, and you are only doing this in order to _transfer_ state between instances. For that, you could use `context.Entry(anEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(someObject)`. Its hard to believe that the source object is mutated in the map operation, and would be interesting to see where is that `product` parameter coming from.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo That was made just in case. I was a little afraid when I saw [this](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/9.0-Upgrade-Guide.html) in 9.0 Upgrade Guide. Also, I've tried `SetValues`, but it doesn't change navigation properties.

Answer (score 2):

When AutoMapper maps collections, it doesn't map entity onto entity; it literally replaces the collection with a new collection of the mapped entities. Because of EF's change tracking, this looks like you have opted to remove all the previously related entities and then add an entirely new set of related entities. You need the [`AutoMapper.Collection`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection) library to handle mapping collections items individually via identifiers.

Comment: Okay. I've checked. Added some 'EqualityComparison' and line add `Startup`. Unfortunately, that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to detach the product from the context because you retrieve another one with the same id. Try the following:

```cs
_mapper.Map(product, productFromDb); // <== HERE
_context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Detached;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried and it throws the same `Exception`. But in the line, which changes state

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: I've posted it in the question description

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried not pulling the item from the DB at all:

```
public async Task<RepositoryResult> UpdateAsync(Product product) {
{
    context.Products.Attach(product);
    context.Entry(product).Collection(p => p.PreparationMethods).Load(); 
    context.Entry(product).Collection(p => p.ProductAttributes).Load(); 

    context.Entry<Products>(product).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RepositoryResult.Success();
}
```

Comment: Hey. That one almost works, but I have the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291585/how-to-update-naviation-property-with-new-values-in-ef-core)

Comment: @Morasiu - I've updated the answer to hopefully include the navigation properties.

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives me the same Exception as in my previous question. Maybe I'm hopeless.

Comment: Don't get downhearted - I'm not sure what the solution is but there will be one. One option - possibly time-consuming would be to write your own mapping layer rather than using AutoMapper. Another thing to try might be to loop through the navigation properties and set each one to have `System.Data.EntityState.Modified`.

Comment: When the desperate time will come, I'll use that solution. Anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Try to detach `productFromDb` apparently `_mapper` attaches `product` and make its state `EntityState.Added` :

```cs
// product has state Detached here
_mapper.Map(product, productFromDb); // <== HERE
// product now has state Added
_context.Entry(productFromDb).State = EntityState.Detached;
_context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: It throws same `Exception` here `_context.Entry(productFromDb).State = EntityState.Detached;`

Answer (score 0):

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Product' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 18}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'

Try to add `AsNoTracking()` like below :

```
var productFromDb = await _context.Products.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(p => p.PreparationMethods)
            .Include(p => p.ProductAttributes)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == product.Id);
```

Reference :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Comment: Okay. But now it's not tracking any changes in the model so it's not updating anything. Or maybe I should change something more?